# How to reduce the APPRTC library size?

Tags: android, webrtc, apprtc, apprtcdemo

In my app , I implemented APPRTC. Before implement the APPRTC my app size is 6MB. After implemented APPRTC My app size went 16 MB. i am using one to one Voice chat only. Can we have any other options to reduce the APP size or webrtc library size? Please suggest..  Thanks..

Note : "libjingle_peerconnection_so.so" liberary size is 10 MB.

Answer (score 0):

You can Split APK using `Gradle.` Like,

```
 // APK splitting
splits {
    abi {
        // Enable APK splitting wrt architecture
        enable true

        // Reset the architectures for which you need to build the APKs for
        reset()

        // Include the architectures for which Gradle is building APKs
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'

        // Set this to false if you don't want an APK that has native code for all architectures
        universalApk false
    }
}

// Assign codes to each architecture
project.ext.versionCodes = ['x86': 0, 'x86_64': 1, 'armeabi-v7a': 2, 'arm64-v8a': 3]

// Add the architecture-specific codes above to base version code, i.e. the version code specified in the defaultConfig{} block
// Example: 2000 is the base version code -> 2000 (x86), 2001 (x86_64), 2002 (armeabi-v7a) & 2003 (arm64-v8a) would be the version codes for the generated APK files
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        output.versionCodeOverride = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI), 0) * 1 + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
}
```

Comment: post analyze apk result of `armeabi-v7a` apk

Comment: app-test-armeabi-v7a-release size is 14MB